# Error Loading Model During Object Detection Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I've been trying to run the object_detection_tutorial located at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection but keep getting an error when trying to load the model.

I get:
`INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore`

when i try to do:

```
tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)
```

I've gone through the installation instructions and done all of that but I can't load the model. Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Question: Have you performed all the steps listed here - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md
When you run the last step there, what happens? Also, can you clarify which directory you are trying to read from

Comment: So I originally ran that last step with Tensorflow 1.14.0 and it worked fine. The tutorial has you install Tensorflow 2.0 though so now if I try running that step again I get error "tensorflow has no attribute contrib". It's frustrating that the installation instructions are for 1.x and the tutorial is 2.0.